# Sort objects properties by a value of a nested property

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm currently trying to sort a objects properties bases on a value of the properties properties if that makes sense.

```
var obj = { 
    1: { name: "Mike", surname: "Smith"},
    2: { name: "Albert", surname: "Einstein"},
    3: { name: "Steve", surname: "Jobs"}
}
```

Say I want to sort the order of these properties by surname so the end result is

```
var obj = { 
    2: { name: "Albert", surname: "Einstein"},
    3: { name: "Steve", surname: "Jobs"},
    1: { name: "Mike", surname: "Smith"}
}
```

Surely there has to be an elegant way of doing this other than putting all the surnames into an array sorting that and then reconstructing the object.

Comment: you could use an array, which is sortable, but not an object, which is actually not.

Comment: @NinaScholz you mean : you could use an array, which is sort able, but not an `object`, which is actually not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: @ozil, it was a typo.

Comment: Its actually ids coming from the database so these might change to anything.

Comment: So they could be any string?

Comment: JS don't guarantee any order of Objects properties (Object properties can't be ordered). Your initial object and result object are absolutely same.

Comment: I get that objects property order can't be guarantied, was just hoping there was a way other than moving it to an array.

Comment: @Ben Aston they are integers the users userid to be exact.

Comment: Is the object created from JSON deserialization?

Comment: I get what you say now, yes it does and get returned as a string representation of the integer.

Comment: This is clearly a duplicated post, but nobody seems to notice that. I think is *n*plicated post,not only twice

Answer (score 4):

Please try this code:

```js
var arr = [
    {
        f_name: 'George',
        l_name: 'Washington',
        age: 279
    },
    {
        f_name: 'Abraham',
        l_name: 'Lincoln',
        age: 202
    },
    {
        f_name: 'Barack',
        l_name: 'Obama',
        age: 50
    }
];

$(function() {
    $('#headings th').click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var asc = (!$(this).attr('asc')); // switch the order, true if not set
        
        // set asc="asc" when sorted in ascending order
        $('#headings th').each(function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('asc');
        });
        if (asc) $(this).attr('asc', 'asc');
        
        sortResults(id, asc);
    });
        
    showResults();
});

function sortResults(prop, asc) {
    arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (asc) return (a[prop] > b[prop]);
        else return (b[prop] > a[prop]);
    });
    showResults();
}

function showResults () {
    var html = '';
    for (var e in arr) {
        html += '<tr>'
            +'<td>'+arr[e].f_name+'</td>'
            +'<td>'+arr[e].l_name+'</td>'
            +'<td>'+arr[e].age+'</td>'
        +'</tr>';
    }
    $('#results').html(html);
}
```

```css
table {
    margin: 3px;
}
table th {
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
table th, table td {
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click on the table headings to sort the results.
<table>
    <thead id="headings">
        <tr>
            <th id="f_name">First Name</th>
            <th id="l_name">Last Name</th>
            <th id="age">Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="results">
        <!-- this will be auto-populated -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This code works but still relays on the original variable being a array, Im actually using angularJS and trying to use ng-repeat on this object and I know it only works with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an object that has an order. That could be an `Array` or `Map`.

You then need to think about your data schema (i.e. the shape of the JSON data emitted from the server). I might move the ID into the objects themselves (the alternative is to make it implicit, which is brittle and error-prone).

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Fred", 
    ...
  }
]
```

At that point it is just a sorting problem.

`Array` has a [sort function on the prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

Note if you need to perform a conversion to an array, you can use `Array.from`:

```js
var obj = { 
  1: { name: "Mike", surname: "Smith" },
  2: { name: "Albert", surname: "Einstein" },
  3: { name: "Steve", surname: "Jobs" },
  length: 4 // largest *zero-based* index 
};

console.log(Array.from(obj));
```

The resulting array will be sparse (have gaps) so you will then need to filter the result to eliminate them:

```
Array.from(obj).filter(populated);

function populated(v) {
  return !!v;
}
```

Comment: I was afraid this is the only way, but I think I can make it work. An copy of this gets used by ng-repeat and only there so I guess changing the map to an array of maps for that is not the end of the world.